# ScrollView doesn't show all my components - React Native

Tags: react-native

My scrollview simply doesn't show all my components on my screen.

How can I fix this? 
As you can see in the code below, there is an image and 4 Text Inputs.
But the scrollview only shows the image and 2 text inputs.
I put a border in the scrollview to see it's size, and is is the size of the entire screen.

Here is my code:

```
    render(){
        return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.myFun} style={styles.choosePhoto}>
                    <Thumbnail large source={this.state.avatarSource} style={styles.thumb}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <Form>
                    <FormItem texto='Name'/>
                    <FormItem texto='CPF' keyboardType={'numeric'}/>
                    <FormItem texto='Email'/>
                    <FormItem texto='Password'/>
                </Form>
            </ScrollView>

        )
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,
    },
    thumb:{
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
    },
    choosePhoto:{
        borderWidth: 1,
        width: '35%',
        height: '35%',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: '25%',
        justifyContent: 'center',    
    },
})
```

Text Input:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Item, Label, Input} from 'native-base';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
export default class FormItem extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <Item style={styles.campo} floatingLabel>
                <Label>{this.props.texto}</Label>
                <Input secureTextEntry={this.props.secureTextEntry} keyboardType={this.props.keyboardType}/>
            </Item>
        )
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    campo:{
        marginRight: '7%',
        marginLeft: '7%',
    },
})
```

What appears on my screen:

[image: App Screen]

Answer (score 0):

It's probably  an issue related with your native base Form component give it an style with flex:1 and i hope it fixes

Comment: It didn't work :(
I also tried to put a Button with TouchableOpacity and the button doesn't show too, any other ideas?

Comment: I also tried deleting the Form component and using only the text Inputs of react native and it didn't work either